# Особые различия между двумя перечисляемыми типами

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Вот обнаружил, что в C# присутствуют два очень похожих перечисляемых типа: `StringComparer и StringComparison`. Интересно, имеют ли они какие либо значительные отличия и области применений? НЕ алиасы ли это, как `string И String`, например ? К примеру:

```
a) StringComparer a = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
b) StringComparison b = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
```

Есть ли разница?

Comment: (Не уверен, что все правильно излагаю, поэтому комментарий, а не ответ.)

Так вот. Это не алиасы, но и значительных отличий нет, кроме того, куда их можно передавать. Разные типы, не замещающие один другой (будет ошибка приведения типов), но подводных камней в их разнице вроде как нет.

Comment: Ааааа, как подводных камней нет, если один это `abstract class`, а второй - `enum`? o0

Comment: Это я и имел в виду под незамещаемостью. Камень, конечно, но не подводный :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) - **не** перечислимый тип, это абстрактный класс, а его поле `OrdinalIgnoreCase` это объект класса `StringComparer`. `StringComparison` это действительно `enum`.

Собственно, разница между ними фундаментальна: `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` это объект, который умеет сравнивать строки, `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` по факту вообще `int`.

Comment: Хм, ну да, точно, абстрактный класс. Не заметил у него почему-то методов, наследуемых от object...ну, исходя из этого, уже становится многое объяснимо. Спасибо!